# How to generate Serial No in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have data in MySQL similar to:

```
NO    Item
-----------------------
 1     A
 1     B
 1     C
 2     A
 3     C
```

But I wanted to generate serial no for that like:

```
SrNo   NO    Item
-----------------------
 1      1     A
 2      1     B
 3      1     C
 1      2     A
 1      3     C
```

Comment: You mean you're "serial" is related to the value of the field "Item" ? Ifso, just calculate a hash of value.

Comment: Yes...Can you please tell me the query?

Comment: Why don't you just use "1A", "1B, "2A", "3C", etc...

Comment: It is not dependent on Item...Please read carefully it is dependent on "NO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results exactly as you are looking for, here is one query:

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = `NO` THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1 
    WHEN @prev_value := `NO` THEN @rank_count := 1 END AS `SrNo`, `NO`, `item`
FROM `Table1`
ORDER BY `NO`, `item`
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab94/45) is the sqlfiddle so you can test it out for yourself.

Comment: Works Very fine...For Five to Seven Values,  But then it gets only one to every row...please help..